# Can a Red Lantern become "good" again?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Can someone who becomes a Red Lantern become "good" again i.e. control the anger and return to normal?

Comment: http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Former_Red_Lantern_Corps_Members

Comment: Comics-wise or does that include the animated series?

Comment: Comics-wise but I would be interested in animated as well.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes.

The best example of this is [Razer](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/razer/4005-83911/), a Red Lantern who rejects his anger, trains with the Blue Lantern Corps, and is eventually followed into space by a blue ring (indicating he'll be the next Blue Lantern).

[image: Razer]

---

There are also other examples that, admittedly, adhere less to the spirit of your question.

Green Lantern **Guy Gardner** once gave into his rage and wielded a red ring for a time:

[image: Guy Gardner]

Green (and then White) Lantern **Kyle Rayner** once wielded all the rings simultaneously.

[image: Kyle Rayner]

Comment: You might want to add Bleez, temporarily cured by Simon Baz's "emerald sight" in _Green Lanterns_ #3 (2016). [Here are the relevant panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4NIK.jpg). Though it was only temporary, and she reverted back when Jessica attacked her.

Comment: Supergirl was also a Red Lantern at one point. https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/4/47/Supergirl_Red_Daughter_of_Krypton.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170213105622